# Rails - Redirection from 2 views to 1 edit_view and back with get-params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I have 2 views, there is on both a edit button.
This button redirect to the **edit_view**.
If I submit there the redirect shoul bring me back to the views where i came from. And pass id params back with get in the URL to one of this views.

Model:

> localhost:3000/order/list > **/order/edit_single_order** >
>   localhost:3000/order/list?id=1
>
> localhost:3000/order/administrate > **/order/edit_single_order** > 
>   /order/administrate

The redirection :

```
    def redirect_to_back_or_default_params(default = root_url, *args)
      if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].present? && request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] != request.env['REQUEST_URI']
        redirect_to :back, *args
      else
        redirect_to default, *args
      end
    end
```

The Controller-redirect :

```
redirect_to_back_or_default_params administrate_order_path(:provider_id => @cart_item.product.provider.id)
```

Comment: store url in session and redirect to url in session upon successful update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : 
I passed the params with store_location

Controller/View :

```
store_location(params[:provider_id])
```

Store_location:

```
  def store_location(args=nil)
    #test to prevent Url's like order/administrate?id=       
    if args.nil?
      session[:return_to] = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"     
    else 
      session[:return_to] = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}?id=#{args}"
    end
  end
```

Redirect :

```
    def redirect_back_or_default(default)
      redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
      session[:return_to] = nil
    end
```